# Handling a "too many values" exception in PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to handle the "too many values" exception in a PLSQL program.
The table is:

[Table structure of emptest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weqOY.png)

But I am not able to handle the exception and the program always shows a pre-defined error.
Anybody has any ideas?

I tried like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOomA.png)

Not getting the user defined message.

Comment: As Pirate explained you are trying to insert a 5th value into a table that has 4 columns only. Here on SO, share them as text instead of pictures. BTW, likely you wouldn't want to store deptname in your employee table but just the deptId.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, in your table you have only four columns.

```
ENO
ENAME
ESAL
DEPTNAME
```

but you are tying to insert five column values.

```
insert into emptest values(v_eno, v_ename, v_esal, v_deptname, v_deptno);
```

**Why are you inserting v_deptno when it is not present in the table?**

Either alter your table and add one more column or update the code to insert four column value only.

Comment: I intentionally did it. I want to handle that exception to return a Custom Message.

Comment: That is not an exception. That is an error. You should try to rectify that error instead of handling.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying will not work. The pl/sql block will not compile because the sql statement is invalid - it has too many values.

I *think* you want to trap the error and show your own error message. But, you need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in order to allow invalid sql in pl/sql.

To trap a specific oracle error with a custom message, use `EXCEPTION_INIT`

Here is an example:

```
create table testa (col1 NUMBER);

set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
DECLARE
  -- unnamed system exception
  too_many_values EXCEPTION; 
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (too_many_values, -00913);   
  c_too_many_values VARCHAR2(512) := 'Dude, too many values !';

BEGIN
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO testa VALUES (1,2)';
  EXCEPTION WHEN   too_many_values THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(c_too_many_values);
  END;
END;
/

Dude, too many values !


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

In you table you only have **four columns**, but you try to insert **five column** so error is generated error.

v_deptno is not your table

change your query as per following

```
 Insert Into emptest values(v_eno, v_ename, v_esal, v_deptname);
```

or add one more column to your table

```
ALTER TABLE emptest ADD DEPTNO Number(4);
```

Comment: The only correct way to insert data into some table (that was not created temporarily from the same statement for the transformation purposes) is to provide column list in `insert` statement and expression list in the `values/select`